# Problems to play ads in Vungle

Tags: java, android, vungle-ads

I am using Vungle SDK 5.1.0.

In Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

[...]

```
<activity android:name="com.vungle.publisher.VideoFullScreenAdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>

    <activity android:name="com.vungle.publisher.MraidFullScreenAdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>

    <activity android:name="com.vungle.publisher.FlexViewAdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

In my first Activity:

```
final VunglePub vunglePub = VunglePub.getInstance();
```

[...]

```
vunglePub.init(this, "XXXXX", new String[] { "PLACEMEXXXXX" }, new VungleInitListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable e){

        }
    });
```

[...]

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    vunglePub.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    vunglePub.onResume();
}
```

In my Main-Activity:

```
final VunglePub vunglePub = VunglePub.getInstance();
final AdConfig globalAdConfig = vunglePub.getGlobalAdConfig();
```

[...]

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    vunglePub.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    vunglePub.onResume();
}
```

If I try to call

```
vunglePub.playAd("PLACEMEXXXXX", globalAdConfig);
```

I get noting. No Ads. And ideas how I can resolve my problem?

Comment: The auto-cached of my PLACEMENTXXXXX is true. "Note that for the auto-cached placement, you don’t need to call loadAd because the SDK will automatically load an ad after initialization. We recommend choosing most viewed placement as your auto-cached selection. "

Answer (score 0):

I am Gabor from Vungle. Is your app set to test mode in our dashboard? If yes, please switch to active mode and try again. Give it 30 minutes to be sure the app is really in active mode.

If you app is in active mode already, please contact us at tech-support@vungle.com with your Vungle APP ID and placement ID, so we can have a deeper look for you.

Thanks

Gabor

Comment: I can only use the "Test Mode", because my app is not published

Comment: Now I can playAds. But I cant call correctly the EventListener :-(

Comment: It is fine to enter an URL like https://vungle.com and switch your app to active mode for the test you are doing. just please enter the real link when your app is going live. Which event listener  is not working for you?